# NSObject may not respond to 'onEnter' (when using iAd in AppDelegate)

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, iad

Using iAd. Getting few warnings.
Below is the code I have put in AppDelegate.m

What is missing?

Warnings are indicated with end of code line

```
-(void)onEnter
{
    [super onEnter]; //<-- NSObject may not respond to this
    adView = [[ADBannerView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    adView.delegate = self;
    adView.requiredContentSizeIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObjects: ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape, ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape, nil];
    adView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape;
    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:adView];
    adView.hidden = YES;
}


-(void)onExit
{
    adView.delegate = nil;
    [adView removeFromSuperview];
    [adView release];
    adView = nil;
    [super onExit]; //<-- NSObject may not respond to this
}



-(void)bannerViewActionDidFinish :(ADBannerView *)banner
    {    
        NSLog(@"bannerViewActionDidFinish called");
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation :(UIInterfaceOrientation)[[CCDirector sharedDirector] deviceOrientation]];
    }
//<-- Instance method deviceOrientation not found (return type defaults to id)
```

What is wrong?  Missing any Class to inherit?

Comment: What are these methods?  I can't find them anywhere.  Are these actually methods that you think you are overriding?  Or are you calling super just randomly?

Comment: Nevermind, I see your cocos2d tag.  Those methods are defined in `CCNode` so you need to inherit from that, not `NSObject`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The onEnter and onExit methods are only available in classes deriving from CCNode. Your class is subclassing from NSObject.

If you send the onEnter/onExit messages manually, simply remove the call to super onXXX because it's superfluous.

Answer (score 1):

You need to inherit from `CCNode`, not `NSObject`

**EDIT** Furthermore, `deviceOrientation` is not a member of `CCDirector` so why are you assuming that it is?

Answer (score 0):

The warnings are there because the methods you are calling, which probably implemented in your superclass `@implementation` are not publicly visible in your `@interface`. Just declare them in your superclass `.h` files.

```
- (UIDeviceOrientation)deviceOrientation;
- (void)onExit;
- (void)onEnter;
```

If you don't want them to be publicly visible, declare them in a category of your subclass `.m` file as you know they exist.

Comment: this doesn't made any effect.

Comment: The superclass is `NSObject` as noted in the title and the comments